# Bound on Bessel function of the first order

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, special-functions

Let $I_1(z)$ be the Bessel function of the first order with purely imaginary argument.

Can we **explicitly** bound $I_1$ on $[0,x]$, where $x>0$ is a real number in terms of $x$?

Comment: Note that $$I_1(iz)=i\,J_1(z)$$. Then see [these](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.14).